# r: How to calculate duration in hh:mm:s to a fixed time in hours but overlapping midnight

Tags: r, dataframe, time, dplyr, lubridate

I have the following `hh:mm:ss` defined in `df$times`

```
     times
1 22:55:00
2 01:05:00
3 21:00:00
```

I want to calculate the duration from `20:00:00` to each of these times. However, some times are after midnight and the duration should in this case be estimated to `20:00:00` the 'following day`

Expected output

```
     times    new
1 22:55:00   2.92 
2 01:05:00   5.08
3 21:00:00  -1.00
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(times = c("22:55:00", "01:05:00", "21:00:00")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We convert to period class with `hms`, create a condition to check whether the compared time value is greater than the 'times', then add 1 day and subtract or else just subtract

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
    mutate(times1 = hms(times), times2 = hms("20:00:00"), 
       new = as.numeric(case_when(times1 < times2 ~ 
      (times1 + hms("24:00:00") - times2), TRUE ~ times2- times1))/3600 ) %>%
   select(times, new)
#     times       new
#1 22:55:00 -2.916667
#2 01:05:00  5.083333
#3 21:00:00 -1.000000
```

Comment: Hi - thank you for input. Unfortunately, `time 2` calculates `18 hours`, but should be `4 hours`.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

mydf <- structure(list(times = c("22:55:00", "01:05:00", "21:00:00")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

mydf %>%
  mutate(
    times = as.ITime(times),
    difference = case_when (
      times > as.ITime("20:00:00") ~ difftime(times, as.ITime("20:00:00")),
      TRUE ~ difftime(as.ITime("23:59:59"), as.ITime("19:59:59")) 
               + difftime(  times, as.ITime("00:00:01"))
    )
  )
```